# Hide the tab if there is no content

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tabs

I have below code with `Brochures` and `Resources` tabs. The code works perfectly fine, the only problem is when any of these tabs are empty the tab does not disappear. The empty tab-content link just remains there. I've explore and applied different scripts but each attempt resulted with fail.

I hope you guys can help me on this.

Sorry my code is little bit long.

```
<div class="publication-slide-container">
    <ul class="tab-links">
    <li class="active"><a href="#brochure">Brochures</a></li>
    <li><a href="#article">Resources</a></li>
    </ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="publication-slide full-slider active" ID="brochure">
    <?php
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, array( 'publication-category', 'publication-type'), $args );

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
  $args = array(
      'post_type'           => 'publication',
      'orderby'             => 'date',
      'order'               => 'ASC',
      'post_status'         => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page'      => - 1,
      'tax_query'           => array(
          'relation' => 'AND',
          array(
              'taxonomy'    => 'publication-category',
              'field'       => 'slug',
              'terms'       => array( $term->slug)
          ),
          array(
              'taxonomy'    => 'publication-type',
              'field'       => 'slug',
              'terms'       => array( 'brochure' )
          )
      )
  );

  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

           // something here

          <?php
          endwhile;
  } 
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
  </div>

<div class="publication-slide full-slider" style="display:none;" ID="article">

    <?php
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, array( 'publication-category', 'publication-type'), $args );

foreach( $terms as $term ) {
  $args = array(
      'post_type'           => 'publication',
      'orderby'             => 'date',
      'order'               => 'DESC',
      'post_status'         => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page'      => 10,
      'tax_query'           => array(
          'relation' => 'AND',
          array(
              'taxonomy'    => 'publication-category',
              'field'       => 'slug',
              'terms'       => array( $term->slug)
          ),
          array(
              'taxonomy'    => 'publication-type',
              'field'       => 'slug',
              'terms'       => array( 'article', 'ASEAN Insiders', 'Expert Commentary' )
          )
      )
  );

  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

        //something here

  <?php
          endwhile;
  } 
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
  </div>

</div>
```

and my script is

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.publication-slide-container .tab-links a').on('click', function(e) {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');


           jQuery('.publication-slide-container ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

            jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code to remove empty tab:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.publication-slide-container .tab-links a').on('click', function(e) {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');


           jQuery('.publication-slide-container ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

            jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });

 // below is my code.
      jQuery('.publication-slide-container .tab-content .publication-slide').each(function() {
        if (!jQuery(this).text().trim()) {   // empty .publication-slide
          jQuery('.publication-slide-container .tab-links')
            .find('a[href="#' + jQuery(this).attr('id')+'"]').parent().remove();   // remove related <li></li>
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks @BendyZhang, it tried but there is no effect. The empty tab still appears.

Comment: @t.cvmk , I make a mistake (missing closure `]` ) about above code. And fixed it.

Comment: thans, but it still does not work. I am adding your script with second script with open closing tag `<script></script>`. Am I doing correct way?

Comment: Yes, any script errors in your console of browser?  If not, pls checking whether the inner html/text of `publication-slide` element is empty. `!$(this).text().trim()` this code is used to check empty.

Comment: yes the inner element is empty. And in my console I get this error,

`Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at (index):679` 

Sorry I did not notice it earlier

Comment: I do not know what's your jQuery version. But you can try to put code like my answer which will be updated later.